# Is there an annotate-like gem for methods in a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, annotate

Sorry if this has been asked before; I searched before posting and I could not find something similar.

My question is whether a gem that provides annotation for a rails project exists or not. That is, let's say I have a rails project that depends on a number of gems and I would like to know
which method in, say, in a rails model corresponds to a method inherited from a gem.

To give you an example, the code that follows includes the method "searchable" that comes from the popular gem 'sunspot_rails':

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :content, :published_at
  has_many :comments

  searchable do
    text :name, :content
  end
end
```

So, is there a gem that would annotate the method searchable telling my that it "comes from" the gem 'sunspot_rails'?

It would really help while reading through the code of a large rails project

Thanx